# how to display images from folder while displaying image by name using php?

Tags: php

I have two folders, `1)- 23feb2016` and `2)- 23feb2016`.
I want to get one image from `folder1` and one from `folder2` , the image name must be unique, like `userid` etc.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <Image src="../images/registered/20115.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></Image> Registered
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <Image src="../images/registered/20115.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></Image> Attendance
    </div>
 </div>
```

[image: same image will be display in model and by submiting it will send flag to DB]

Comment: `my html code is this`  where?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Save image name with `timestamp` then

Comment: Use date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '_' . uniqid() for unique image name

Comment: give table structure please .

Comment: <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <Image src="../images/registered/20115.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></Image> Registered
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                <Image src="../images/registered/20115.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></Image> Attendance
                                </div>
                            </div>

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya i am using it just for comparing picture , the one folder is registration folder where all the images of registered employees will be saved and the other folder will be datewise folder means 03/07/2016 folder is for today images , and all the images will be stored with userid name like (201114.jpg), every time i click on transiction id it popup the registered image and the image in the date range folder with the same userid. can you please give me logic how to display the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following approach to find the unique files.

```
//path to directory to scan
$directory1 = "./folder1/";
$directory2 = "./folder2/";

//get all Image files with a .jpg extension.
$jpgFolder1 = glob($directory1 . "*.jpg");
$jpgFolder2 = glob($directory2 . "*.jpg");

$UniqeImage[];

if(($jpgFolder1 != null) && ($jpgFolder2 != null))
{
    $UniqeImage = array_unique(array_intersect($jpgFolder1, $jpgFolder2));
}
```

Now the Array Variable $UniqeImage[] contains the Unique file names using this you can construct the HTML

```
foreach($UniqeImage as $img)
{
    echo("<div class='col-md-12'>");
    echo("    <div class='col-md-6'>");
    echo("        <Image src='../images/Folder1/" . $img . ".jpg' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'></Image> Registered");
    echo("    </div>");
    echo("    <div class='col-md-6'>");
    echo("        <Image src='../images/Folder2/" . $img . ".jpg' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'></Image> Attendance");
    echo("    </div>");
    echo("</div>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help  the folders must be dynamically changing as per date .. means each date have own folder of images and the name of folder will be the date and image name will be userid.jpg like this .

Comment: Happy with your reply. The answer really fulfilled your requirement means, then mark it as your Answer.

Comment: it displays all the images while i have to check for the image with folder name and image with transiction ,